# Dropbox API: how to disable or pause syncing when on cellular?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using both Sync and Datastore APIs in my Android project. I want to add a wifi only mode to save user cellular data consumption.

Is there a way to pause and queue the upload and download in background, but still keep the library functioning (like insertion/deletion in datastore, accessing local cached file etc)?

If there's no such thing in Dropbox API, I need to manually track changes on cellular, and apply them after the device is connected to WIFI, ... and stop and mark progress when switched to cellular. This can get complicated.

Comment: Here's a relevant thread on the Dropbox API forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=102173.

Comment: @smarx The discussion was 8 months ago, on the file syncing, does Dropbox plan to add control apis to pause/stop syncing? For my case it's datastore + file, manual control would be even trickier.

Comment: Here's a more recent thread (specifically about datastores), but nothing has really changed: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=113055#post-598469.

Comment: @smarx On Dropbox end, is there any plan to accommodate this request? I feel it's a fairly common situation, and should not be too difficulty to implement inside the library.

Comment: No plans that I know of, but we're already tracking it as a feature request.